# Crash on sending Data though POST request

Tags: android, post, crash, request, http-post

I'm pretty new in Android, so please be patient:)

I need to send data entered by the user to our dataBase (CRM). 
It's crash when the user click on submit button to send the data.

When I put the function postDataForOrenG() inside OnClick(), it's crash, when I don't put it ("//postDataForOrenG()"), it goes to other activity with no issue.

Please find bellow my code and the errors from LogCat.

public class ConTct extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

```
Button mButton;
EditText mFullName, mEmail, mDialZone, mPhone;
static WebView mWebView;
static ProgressBar mProgressBar;

public static final String myURL = "http://iphoneapp.optionrally.com:5757";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.contct);

    mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitRegisterButton);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mFullName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    mEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    mDialZone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.countryPhonePrefix);
    mPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

    mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TheWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://media-dispatcher.com/tds/mobile/?mdaf=TestTradingSignalsTest");
    mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);


    GetCountryZipCode();



    //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
    ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(AppManager.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
}//oncreate()



private static class TheWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



}//MyWebViewClient


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);


}//onStart()

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();

    //Stop the analytics tracking
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);


    sendDatatoGAfromOnStop();

}//onStop()



public void sendDatatoGAfromOnStop(){

    String name = mFullName.getText().toString();   
    name=name.replace("@", "|");
    name=name.replace(".", "!");


    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
    email=email.replace("@", "|");
    email=email.replace(".", "!");  


    String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();
    phone=phone.replace("@", "|");
    phone=phone.replace(".", "!");



    Tracker t = ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("Ostp// " + name)
    .setAction(email)
    .setLabel(phone)
    .build());
}

public void sendDatatoGAfromOnTouch(){

    String name = mFullName.getText().toString();   
    name=name.replace("@", "|");
    name=name.replace(".", "!");


    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
    email=email.replace("@", "|");
    email=email.replace(".", "!");  


    String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();
    phone=phone.replace("@", "|");
    phone=phone.replace(".", "!");



    Tracker t = ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("Otch// " + name)
    .setAction(email)
    .setLabel(phone)
    .build());
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (GeneralValidation()==true){




        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for your registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThanksZuser.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
```

// HERE IS THE FUNCTION THAT SEND DATA TO OUR DATABASE

```
        postDataForOrenG();

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*Fill the form correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}//onclick()


public boolean GeneralValidation(){
    boolean result = false;

    final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pass = mFullName.getText().toString();
    final String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();


    if(!isValidEmail(email) || !isValidFullName(pass) || !isValidPhoneNumber(phone)){

        if(!isValidEmail(email)){
            mEmail.setError("Invalid email");
            mEmail.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mEmail.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if(!isValidFullName(pass)){
            mFullName.setError("Invalid name. You have to input at least 3 characters");
            mFullName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mFullName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if(!isValidPhoneNumber(phone)){
            mPhone.setError("Not Valid Number");
            mPhone.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mPhone.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }else{
        result=true;

    }
    return result;
}//GeneralValidation

// validating phone
private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phone2) {

    boolean check;

    if(phone2.length() < 6 || phone2.length() > 13){
        check = false;
    }else{
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
}


// validating email 
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating full name
private boolean isValidFullName(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String GetCountryZipCode(){
    String CountryID="";
    String CountryZipCode="";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
        String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
        if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
            CountryZipCode=g[0];
            break;  
        }
    }
    mDialZone.setText( "+ " + CountryZipCode);
    return CountryZipCode;
}//GetCountryZipCode



//if the user touched the submit, button, send the data to ga

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        if (GeneralValidation()==true){

            sendDatatoGAfromOnTouch();
        }

    } else {


    }


    return false;
}//onTouch



//HERE IS THE CODE THAT SEND DATA TO OUR DATABASE



public void postDataForOrenG() {

    String l_BrokerId, l_IP, l_AreaPhonePrefix, l_LastName, l_PassWord, l_Campaign, l_SubCampaign, l_CountryID, l_City, l_Adress, l_IsDemo;

    l_BrokerId = "my broker";
    l_IP="my ip";
    l_AreaPhonePrefix= " my area phone prefix";
    l_LastName= "my last name";
    l_PassWord="my password";
    l_Campaign="my campaign";
    l_SubCampaign="my sub campaign";
    l_CountryID= "my country id";
    l_City = " my city";
    l_Adress= " my adress";
    l_IsDemo="this is MIMI's DEMO!!";

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iphoneapp.optionrally.com:5757");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brokerId", l_BrokerId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ip", l_IP));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("areaPhonePrefix", l_AreaPhonePrefix));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", l_LastName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", l_PassWord));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("campaign", l_Campaign));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subCampaign", l_SubCampaign));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryId", l_CountryID)); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", l_City)); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", l_Adress)); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isDemo", l_IsDemo)); 

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryPhonePrefix", mDialZone.getText().toString())); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", mPhone.getText().toString())); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", mFullName.getText().toString())); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail.getText().toString())); 

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}//postDataForOrenG
```

}//ConTct.class

Here's the error from the logCat :

11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121): Process: com.Signals4Trading.push.android, PID: 16121
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.ConTct.postDataForOrenG(ConTct.java:458)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.ConTct.onClick(ConTct.java:245)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-06 10:00:52.112: E/AndroidRuntime(16121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Many thanks for your help:))

Comment: It's seems that you didn't add permission to the Manifest file

Comment: Oh Thank you! I add the bluetooth permission in my manifest. I run again my app and it crashes again. Please see the log from my logCat, I edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

> BLUETOOTH permission is missing!

This is your error. Add permission in manifest for Bluetooth access.

Comment: Oh Thank you! I add the bluetooth permission in my manifest. I run again my app and it crashes again. Please see the log from my logCat, I edit it again.

Comment: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" is the culprit.
Your method "postDataForOrenG()" should be call off-UI i.e. all the network requests and long running tasks should be called off-UI, search for AsyncTask or Thread and Handler combination for network calls.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I understand the general concept. How can I   do this inside my code? Please help me with the off-UI thread you told me about

Comment: Link 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html


Link 2: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Oh Thank you, I see in Vogella's example that he's using Get Request, I am using Post request. Is it better for me to try using Get request as I see in Vogella's exaple?